# *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails

`2012/10/26 14:57:49 [error] 14180#0: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 24.0.20.48, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:81/", host: "107.20.184.144"`

This is the `nginx` error that I get which results in a 503 error. Not sure what to do about it. [connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream](https://serverfault.com/questions/317393/connect-failed-111-connection-refused-while-connecting-to-upstream) said to use `php-fpm`, but I'm using Rails, so I think it's a different error. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thank you

**EDIT**: If it matters, this machine has Apache2 running on port `81` it seems. Not sure what that has to do with Rails though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nginx is trying to pass upstream to a web server on port 81, as you configured it.

However, you probably aren't running Rails on port 81; by default `thin` and some other Rails web servers listen on port 3000.

Double check the port number that your Rails app is listening on, and make sure it matches what you have configured in nginx.

You also need to make sure that the upstream server is actually running. It could just be stopped.

Comment: How do I check the port that Rails is running on? I'm not too familiar with Rails, and have inherited this project

Comment: What is the `upstream server` and how do I see if it's running?

Comment: Your edit says what the upstream server is.

Comment: Okay - so it appears that Apache2 is running on port 81, but when I hit it, I get a `503 Service Unavailable - No server is available to handle this request.` error. So I guess the issue lies with Apache?